# Nicer way to change color of multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

i used jQuery to change the color of my buttons based on a click event. The code works and is "easy" to read, but i guess pretty horrible, when i will later have 20+Buttons which will also manipulate HTML.

```
function R1() {
    $("#R1").css("background-color", "red")
  $("#R2").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R3").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R4").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R5").css("background-color", "green")
  }

function R2() {
  $("#R1").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R2").css("background-color", "red")
  $("#R3").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R4").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R5").css("background-color", "green")
  }

function R3() {
  $("#R1").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R2").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R3").css("background-color", "red")
  $("#R4").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R5").css("background-color", "green")
  }
function R4() {
  $("#R1").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R2").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R3").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R4").css("background-color", "red")
  $("#R5").css("background-color", "green")
  }

function R5() {
  $("#R1").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R2").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R3").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R4").css("background-color", "green")
  $("#R5").css("background-color", "red")
  }


document.getElementById("R1").addEventListener("click", R1)
document.getElementById("R2").addEventListener("click", R2)
document.getElementById("R3").addEventListener("click", R3)
document.getElementById("R4").addEventListener("click", R4)
document.getElementById("R5").addEventListener("click", R5)
```

Can you help me to write that in a good programming style?

Comment: Since there isn't a functional problem with your code the code review stack exchange might be a better choice for you to ask this. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using JQuery, you can simply attach the `click` event to the button and when it is clicked change the `background-color` to `red` for this button and set the `background-color` of other buttons, except this, to `green`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $(this).css("background", "red").siblings().css("background", "green");
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='R1'>Click R1</button>
<button id='R2'>Click R2</button>
<button id='R3'>Click R3</button>
<button id='R4'>Click R4</button>
<button id='R5'>Click R5</button>
```

Comment: @MarkusLnGa You can tick the answer if it was really helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function that takes a selector and a color as argument.

```
function changeColor(selector, color) {
  $(selector).css('background-color', color);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
changeColor('button', 'blue');
```

or

```
changeColor('button', '#0000FF');
```

in the click event you can just set the color of every button to red and then color of the clicked button to something else. You don't even need a function for that, you can just do it directly with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the single click event to all elements and set green/red color in click event based on clicked elements context(`this`):

```
var $ugSeriesDom = $('[id^=R]');
$ugSeriesDom.click(function(){
  $ugSeriesDom.css("background-color", "green");
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f983w337/)**

Answer (score 0):

Give all your buttons the same class attribute, so for example in your HTML class="myButtons", then you could write one function which takes an index value of the button you want to change the color on:

```
//Pass in the index of the button who's color needs changed and the color to change it to
function ChangeButtonColor(index, color){
    //Grab all buttons with JQuery selector
    const buttons = $('.myButtons');
    //Change the color of the button at said index to color passed
    $($(buttons)[index]).css('background-color', color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The clean way is to use CSS classes, not to set css directly. That way you can easily change more CSS properties than only one (for example, changing also the border.

So, you would define something like this in your css file:

```
button {
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px yellow;
}
```

Then use javascript to add the class to the clicked button, and remove it for the others.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
      $('button').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
  });
```